# Error when trying to create a ticketTool command with my discordjs v14 bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a ticketTool command, and when I use the command, this error occurs

```
ReferenceError: create is not defined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\commands\ticketTool\createTicketEmbed.js:44:19)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\events\interaction-create.js:16:18)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\index.js:76:44)
    at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)        
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)       
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:494:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
ReferenceError: create is not defined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\commands\ticketTool\createTicketEmbed.js:44:19)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\index.js:90:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)        
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)       
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:494:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\index.js:96:4)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: 'There was an error while executing this command!',
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: 64,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1104799756888309820/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEwNDc5OTc1Njg4ODMwOTgyMDprRTNWMUY4NzY2R3plZkhBUVF0RFlhR09jcjZvSXhYejZ5dVI1MTZIUE1naGpnYll2ck9Lb3ZZelRuOHExS0hLckd4V1hIbXBEcEpkdzNrRG9wMkxDUks0VTRRbGtYcnZ2SVNIV1AxQTJ6Yll0SVVOMHd1R2NER09teW5jclNIaQ/callback'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

I am using this code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ButtonStyle, ButtonBuilder, ActionRowBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('create-ticket')
    .setDescription('Creates a ticket')
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageMessages)
    .addChannelOption((option) =>
    option
  .setName('channel')
  .setDescription('The channel you want to send it to or folder')
  .setRequired(true)
)
.addChannelOption((option) =>
    option
    .setName('ticket-folder')
    .setDescription('The folder than you would like the tickets to be created in')
    .setRequired(true)
),





permissionsRequired: [PermissionFlagsBits.ManageMessages],
botPermissions: [PermissionFlagsBits.ManageMessages],

    async execute(interaction) {
        const channel1 = interaction.options.getChannel('channel')
        const ticketFolder = interaction.options.getChannel('ticket-folder')

            const embed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Create a ticket')
            .setDescription(`Tap on the button below to create a ticket`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor('Green')

            const ticketButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('create')
            .setLabel('Create')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
            .setEmoji('')
            const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(create);

            await channel1.send({embeds: [embed1], components: [row]})


            const confirmation = await response.awaitMessageComponent();

            if (confirmation.customId === 'create'){
                const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`${interaction.member.username} | ticket`, {
                    type: 'text',
                    parent: ticketFolder.id,
                  });
                  await channel.permissionOverwrites.set([
                    {
                      id: guild.roles.everyone, // this sets the default permissions for everyone
                      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], // deny everyone from viewing the channel
                    },
                    {
                      id: guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Moderator'), // replace this with the role ID of your moderators
                      allow: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'MANAGE_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'], // allow moderators to manage the channel
                    },
                  ]);
                  
            }
            const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Ticket Created')
            .setDescription(`${interaction.member.username} has created a ticket!\nTap on the close button to close the ticket`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setAuthor({ name: Guildmember.user.tag, iconURL: Guildmember.user.displayAvatarURL() })
            .setColor('#FF0000')

            const ticketCloseButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('close')
            .setLabel('Close')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
            .setEmoji('❌')

            const row1 = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(close);

            await channel.send({
                embeds: [embed2],
                components: [row1],
              })

            const confirmation1 = await response.awaitMessageComponent();
             if (confirmation.customId === 'close'){
                const channelDeleteEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle('Closing Ticket')
                .setDescription('The ticket will close in 5 seconds')
                .setColor('#FF0000')
                .setTimestamp()
                await channel.send({embeds: [channelDeleteEmbed]})
                setTimeout(() => {
                    channel.delete();
                  }, 5000);
             }

  }   
    };
```

I have deferred in my interactionCreate event:

```
try {
            interaction.deferReply()
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error executing ${interaction.commandName}`);
            console.error(error);
        }
```

and I am not using editReply because I am sending in a specific channel.
Does anyone know why I have this error and how I can fix it?

I am making a ticketTool command for my bot and I have the error above, my code is supplied.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the full error message with stack trace.

Comment: Here, I have added the full erorr

Answer (score 1):

This would work as a comment, but I think it's the answer you're looking for. So, your code says:

```
            .setEmoji('')
            const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(create);
```

But it seems like `create` in `addComponents` doesn't exist, which leads you to get the `create is not defined` error, which then leads to the `Unknown interaction` error.

I'm pretty sure you meant `.addComponents(ticketButton);` and not `.addComponents(create);` so try changing it to that and it should fix your issue! If it does, remember to click the grey checkmark next to this answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: firstly, in the docs it has this:
``` const confirm = new ButtonBuilder()
   .setCustomId('confirm')
   .setLabel('Confirm Ban')
   .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);

  const cancel = new ButtonBuilder()
   .setCustomId('cancel')
   .setLabel('Cancel')
   .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);

  const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
   .addComponents(cancel, confirm);``` they dont define cancel or confirm

Comment: I'm confused. You've put code in that comment that defines confirm and cancel (`const confirm =`, `const cancel =`).

Comment: oh my, I am so stupid, sorry :)

Comment: so it would be this: `.addComponents(ticketButton);`

Comment: Yes it would be. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark my answer as the solution!

Comment: Also, firstly, the embed is sending twice, and secondly I am having this error: DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required, its coming from here: ` const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(`${interaction.member.username} | ticket`, {
                    type: 'text',
                    parent: ticketFolder.id,
                  });`